# JOGL vs JAVA3D for building FEM 3D solvers

Tags: java, jogl, java-3d

I am building an electromagnetic solver which involves computing the charge distribution on a 3D surface and hence involves mesh generation and implementing other constituents of FEM. The user should be able to drag, rotate and scale the meshed figure and the figure should render preferably with shadows. The final solved figure is to be painted with a color distribution which is in accordance with the density/magnitude of charge distribution. I was wondering whether JAVA3D or JOGL would be a good approach to building this app. I know JAVA3D uses JOGL but I have heard that JOGL is not as OOPS friendly as JAVA3D which might complicate the task. I was wondering if anyone could clarify the performance benefits of JOGL vs JAVA3D and what the strengths of each are.

one of the comparisons I referred to was https://javajosh.blogspot.in/2006/12/jogl-vs-java3d.html

Comment: I think it's not the right place to talk about that and the article you quote is terribly old: JOGL and Java3D are maintained by the JogAmp community now, Java3D supports only OpenGL since its version 1.6.0 (I dropped all renderers not using JOGL), ... Both options are viable, Java3D isn't abandoned, a new contributor plans to add Android support. If you know the basics of computer graphics but if you don't want to learn OpenGL, you can pick any scenegraph API based on JOGL.

Comment: @gouessej Thanks, I started with JOGL and I am finding it really good.